# How can I combine MangoHud and game variables in the steam launch options?

Tags: steam, black-mesa

How do I use this option: `-oldgameui` with the options `MANGOHUD=1 MANGOHUD_CONFIG=full %command%`?
I've already tried it different ways, but any option where they're together does not work.

Comment: Are you using Vulkan? And why do you use the `-oldgameui` variable?

Comment: Hello Joachim, I'm just because the new UI doesn't appear when I use Vulkan, it only appears when I use Opengl, however I can't see the mangohud view (Vukan's hud)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe I got the solution and it was so simple.

> MANGOHUD=1 MANGOHUD_CONFIG=full %command% '-oldgameui'

For you who have the same problem, combine the variavis that will work, now I can see the vukan hud modified with MangoHUD and use the old ui game menu.

Information, the new ui game menu does not appear on the screen using dxvk/vulkan.

Regards,

Gabriel